# Bind to grid by selecting data from tow different tables?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have two tables in my database named...Requests and Balance tracker which has no relation....but i want to select data from two tables and binf it two grid...

Requests

```
          EmpID   |EmpRqsts|EmpDescription|ApproverID
           1      |asdfsb  |sadbfsbdf     |1
           2      |asbfd   |sjkfbsd       |1
```

Balance Tracker

```
          EmpId|BalanceAmnt|LastUpdated
         | 1   |5000       |sdfbk
         | 2   |3000       |sjbfsh
```

Employee Table

```
      EmpId|EmpName
       1   |Anil
       2   |Raghu
```

Now Balance tracker has ForeignKey column  of EmployeeTable... What I want is to select [EmpName ] from EmpTable [EmpRqsts] from [Requests] and [BalanceAmnt][LastUpdated] from [Balance Tracker] and bind it to grid

This is my stored procedure I am using to retrieve the data

```
create procedure SP_GetEmployeeRequests
    (@ApproverName varchar (50))
as
begin
    select 
         EmployeeDetails.Emp_Username,
         RequestDetails.Request_Amount,
         RequestDetails.Request_description,
         BalanceTracker.Balance_Amount,
         BalanceTracker.LastApproval,
         BalanceTracker.LastUdated
     from 
         EmployeeDetails, RequestDetails, BalanceTracker
     where 
         EmployeeDetails.Emp_ID = RequestDetails.Emp_ID
         and BalanceTracker.Emp_ID = RequestDetails.Emp_ID
         and RequestDetails.Approved_ID = (select Approved_ID 
                                           from ApprovalDetails  
                                           where Approved_By = @ApproverName)
end
```

Everything is fine till here but this query is retrieving only the column names. But not the values of the tables..can any one help me whats wrong in my query..

Comment: Why has Requests no EmpId? It's storing the name instead of the FK. Can both be joined by the name?

Comment: No the Empname In request tabel is inserted via a textbox manually by the Employee..

Comment: No the Empname In request tabel is inserted via a textbox manually by the Employee..

Comment: So how is the Employee table required at all because you're getting all informations from the other tables? You want a cross-join between Requests
 and Balance Tracker,  since they are not related to each other?

Comment: See i have other table which are realted to employee table....now there is a approver on his login based the data should be binded to grid...if approver with ID=1 logins the  requests attached to his ID should be Binded to the grid

Comment: do u want to make any changes in my tables...

Comment: I changed my table taken EmpId in rqsts table With foriegn key from Employee Table..now can any one help me when if approver with ID=1 logins the requests attached to his ID should be Binded to the grid..i should display name of the Employee In the grid instead of ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my answer thanks for evere one who tried to help me....i am posting my answer,so that it can be help full to any one in need...

```
 CREATE procedure SP_GetEmployeeRequests
(
     @ApproverName varchar (50)
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT PTS_Employee.Emp_Username, PTS_Requests.Request_RequestedAmount, PTS_Requests.Request_Description, PTS_BalanceTracker.Balance_BalanceAmount, PTS_BalanceTracker.Balance_LastApproval, PTS_BalanceTracker.Balance_LastUpdated
FROM PTS_Employee  JOIN PTS_Requests  ON PTS_Employee.Emp_ID = PTS_Requests.Emp_ID 
JOIN PTS_BalanceTracker  ON PTS_BalanceTracker.Emp_ID = PTS_Requests.Emp_ID
JOIN PTS_Approval  ON PTS_Approval.Approval_ApprovedID  = PTS_Requests.Approval_ApprovedID
WHERE PTS_Approval.Approval_ApprovedBY = @ApproverName 

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select t1.EmpName,t2.EmpRqsts,t3.BalanceAmnt,t3.LastUpdated from EmpTable as t1,Requests as t2,Balance_tracker as t3 where t1.sno=t2.sno and t1.sno=t3.sno", conn);
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt1);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```